# spreading/dividing (0.0 to 1.0) by a single number or range (0,inf)

Tags: python, normalization

What I need is to divide/spread 0 to 1. according to single number which is more than 2.
like number 5 will be divided like this

```
0.00  
0.25
0.50
0.75
1.00
```

5 values in a list

and my other question is what to do to get a sequence like this where middle number is 1 and first and last number is 0 , if number is 10.

```
0.00
0.25
0.50
0.75
1.00
1.00
0.75
0.50
0.25
0.00
```

10 item in list
how to this in python via loop ?

Answer (score 2):

## Evenly spaced numbers

From the numpy [linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) documentation:

> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.

Exactly what we need to solve your first problem.

#### Code example

```
import numpy as np

def spread(n):
    return np.linspace(0, 1, n)
```

## Mirroring list

For the second question we can just reuse the array from the first question, invert it and append it. We just have to integer divide `//` your number by 2 (assuming it is divisible by 2) to get the number to pass to `spread`. You get a reverse version of a list/tuple/numpy array doing the following:

```
my_list[::-1]
```

#### Code examples

So your function would look something like:

```
import numpy as np

def updown(n):
    first_half = spread(n//2)
    return np.r_[first_half, first_half[::-1]]
```

You could also flip the array using [np.flipud](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) and instead of [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) you could use [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np

def updown(n):
    first_half = spread(n//2)
    return np.concatenate((first_half, np.flipud(first_half)))
```

Or if you do not need arrays in the end you could do (the same as in a different answer):

```
import numpy as np

def spread(n):
    return list(np.linspace(0, 1, n))

def updown(n):
    first_half = spread(n//2)
    return first_half + first_half[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

the first part is easy:

```
def spread(n):
    return tuple(i/(n-1) for i in range(n))
```

and with that you can create the second by concatenating the tuple from above with the reversed tuple:

```
def updown(n):
    tpl = spread(n//2)
    return tpl + tpl[::-1]
```

if `n` is odd `updown(n)` will be the same as `updown(n-1)`...